# Merge Replication Subscriber does not Expire or cleaned up

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a merge repliaction with retention period set to 1 day. Allow anonymous Subscriptions is set to `False`.

[image: Merge Replication Retention Period]

I Add 2 subscribers. One of the subscriber machine name is wrong, so it is inaccessible. On Repliaction monitor, this inaccessible subscription keeps trying to connect and fails with could not connect to subscriber error.

It has been days, but this subscriber still exists. It does not expire. Running Expired subscription clean up job succeed, but the subscription  does not got removed from subscribers.

[image]

What is the possible reason for this not to work?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to drop the merge subscription, if so there is a system SP you can use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropmergesubscription-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: No, I want Merge replicaton to drop this subscription when retention period + grace period completes without successful syncronization. Documents says when retention period passses without any successfull syncronization, then the subscriber expires, if time equatl to retention period passes again, the the subscriber is dropped from replication.   Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/subscription-expiration-and-deactivation?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Are you sure it is a Push subscription ?

Comment: yes, we do not use pull subscriptions.